# Extend the length of a plot axis in R?

Tags: r, plot

How do you extend the axis line in R to cover the extent of your data? For example, in

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUvp3.png]

my data goes to about 2100 and I would like the line for the x axis to go that far, but not make a tickmark or label at 2100. Is this even possible in R?

Here is the code used to make the above plot:

```
hist(x,breaks=50,xlab="...",main="",xlim=c(0,2100))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use two axis commands; one for the axis line and another for the ticks and labels.

```
set.seed(2); x <- rlnorm(1000, log(130))
hist(x, breaks=seq(0, 3000, by=200), xlim=c(0,2100), xaxt="n")

axis(1, at=c(0,2100), labels=c("",""), lwd.ticks=0)
axis(1, at=seq(0 , 2000, by=200), lwd=0, lwd.ticks=1)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! that does the trick. i can't believe i didn't think of that.

Answer (score 3):

As the famous quote

```
R> fortunes::fortune("yoda")

Evelyn Hall: I would like to know how (if) I can extract some of
the information from the summary of my nlme.
Simon Blomberg: This is R. There is no if. Only how.
   -- Evelyn Hall and Simon 'Yoda' Blomberg
      R-help (April 2005)
R>
```

says "*There is no if. Only how.*".

You can set any axis labels you want by

- suppressing the default axis labels and
- setting the axis labels you want.

Start with `help(axis)`

Comment: I looked into axis and got a bit closer http://imgur.com/g0f1Q with
    par(usr=c(0,max(x),0,1200))
    hist(x,breaks=50,xlab="...",main="",xlim=c(0,2100),xaxt="n")
    axis(1,at=seq(0,2500,500),labels=seq(0,2500,500))
but now there is more of the axis line than I'd like, even though I say to trim it at max(x) which is 2074. After plotting, par("usr")[2] gives 2184.

Comment: Sure, but the same quote holds for assembler, too. And quite often when I program in R, I wonder whether that wouldn't even be faster...

Answer (score 3):

With hist() you can control the location of the ticks and labels with axis:

```
hist( rlnorm(1000, log(130) ), breaks=seq(0, 3000, by=200), xlim=c(0,2100) , axes=FALSE)
axis(1, at=seq(0 , 2000, by=200)
```

If you wanted to see every 200 interval labeled you can rotate the labels with the las argument:

```
axis(1, at=seq(0 , 2000, by=200) , las=2)
```