# Change histogram scale

Tags: r, histogram

I am creating a histogram using R. Since none of my data points are between 95 and 100, it currently just ends the x-scale at 95. Even still, for the purpose of comparison, I would like it to extend to 100 and just have an empty bar between 95 and 100. Is there any way to do this? I've attached an image showing how my histogram is currently presented. Here is the code associated:

```
hist(Data$SR, 
     col = "skyblue2",
     ylim = c(0,5), 
     main = "Grade 9 Science Marks", 
     breaks = 11, 
     xlab = "Mark", 
     xaxt = "n")

axis(1, 
     at = seq(40, 100, by = 5), 
     labels = c("40", "45", "50", "55", "60", "65", "70",
                "75", "80", "85", "90", "95", "100"))
```

I would like for the solution to this to be using the `hist()` function, as I am not at all familiar with `ggplot2.`

EDIT: This is not similar to the post in which it was flagged for. I am trying to make it extend to 100 and have a tick mark that says 100, unlike the post that's apparently similar to this one.

[image: Image Attached]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extend the length of a plot axis in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598224/extend-the-length-of-a-plot-axis-in-r)

Comment: Try to add `xlim = c(40, 100)`, to your `hist` call.

Comment: Thank you very much. That fixed the problem.