# Is there a way to eliminate the bold lines on the x and y axes of this R line plot?

Tags: r, axis, line-plot

I am plotting very basic data from a .CSV in Posit Cloud. The plot itself looks how I want it to, but the x and y axes both have a bit of bolding along the middle of the axis lines, and I would like to remove these. The problem can be seen in the first image below, and I've highlighted the bolder part in the image below it.

[image: bold parts highlighted]

An example of the code that reproduces the issue and is the same code as mine (minus the data):

```
#base R plot definition
plot(
  #define axes
  x= 1:13, 
  y= 3:15,
  
  #customise axes
  xaxs = "i", 
  yaxs = "i",
  type="l", 
  col="#32a852", 
  bty = "l",
  
  #labels
  xlab = 'Bias Current [mA]', 
  ylab = "Voltage [V]", 
  main ="IV Characteristic of 1270nm Laser")
```

I realise that the axes do not both start at 0, and if they did, then this wouldn't be an issue, but I don't want to add dead space into the plot.

I have tried removing the axes by setting `axes=FALSE` in the plot definition, and then adding the axes back in separately, but I ended up with the same result, but produced in a more complex way.

Comment: @MrFlick I've added a link to a new image where I've highlighted what I mean. It's a bit subtle, I do admit, but it's as if the linewidth of the axis is not uniform along the entire axis, with it a little bit wider along the highlighted part.

Comment: It's very possible that if you switch to the AGG graphics device--install the `ragg` package and set your default graphics device to use AGG, [see the readme for some instructions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ragg/readme/README.html)--it will fix the issue without any code changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is overplotting of the box and the axis line. As mentioned in comments, the AGG graphics device provided in the `ragg` package might solve the issue. If not, you can plot the axis ticks without the lines:

```
plot(
  #define axes
  x= 1:13, 
  y= 3:15,
  
  #customise axes
  xaxs = "i", 
  yaxs = "i",
  type="l", 
  col="#32a852", 
  axes = FALSE,
  
  #labels
  xlab = 'Bias Current [mA]', 
  ylab = "Voltage [V]", 
  main ="IV Characteristic of 1270nm Laser")

box(bty = "l")
axis(side = 1, lwd = 0, lwd.ticks = 1)
axis(side = 2, lwd = 0, lwd.ticks = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Installing and using the ragg package did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Rui but a little simpler, since `axis` will automatically keep your breaks and labels as they were, without adding the 'dead space' down at 0 you were keen to avoid:

```r
plot(x = 1:13, y = 3:15, type = "l", col = "#32a852", 
  xlab = 'Bias Current [mA]', 
  ylab = "Voltage [V]", 
  main = "IV Characteristic of 1270nm Laser")

axis(1, lwd = 0, lwd.ticks = 1)
axis(2, lwd = 0, lwd.ticks = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The artifact in the question's plis not bold  l, it's over plotting the axis on other axis lines.
Does this solve it? Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4607746/8245406) to another question.

```r
plot(
  #define axes
  x= 1:13, 
  y= 3:15,
  
  #customise axes
  axes = FALSE,
  xlim = c(0, 13),
  ylim = c(0, 15),
  type="l", 
  col="#32a852", 
  bty = "l",
  
  #labels
  xlab = 'Bias Current [mA]', 
  ylab = "Voltage [V]", 
  main ="IV Characteristic of 1270nm Laser")

axis(1, at = c(-1,13), labels = c("",""), lwd.ticks = 0)
axis(1, at = seq(0, 13, by=2), lwd = 0, lwd.ticks = 1)

axis(2, at = c(-1, 15), labels = c("",""), lwd.ticks = 0)
axis(2, at = seq(0, 15, by=2), lwd = 0, lwd.ticks = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>